# React inline styles, applying styles from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using `npm-inline-css` module, I'm trying to change certain page elements colors, when storing the styles in a state. I set the state here:

```
setHeaderStyle: function(data){
    var headerStyles = this.state.defaultStyles;

    if(data) {
        headerStyles.backgroundColor = data.first_colour;
        headerStyles.color = data.theme;
    }
    this.setState({
        branding: data,
        headerStyles: headerStyles
    });
   },
```

Then I'm trying to apply the styles to the component:

```
  render: function (){
    return (
        <div className="our-schools-app">
          <InlineCss stylesheet="
            & .button {
                color: {{this.state.color}};
            }
            " />
            <RouteHandler />  
        </div>
    );
}
```

But they output like below. How can I set the inline styles? Or a better way I can do this?

```
<style scoped="" data-reactid=".0.0.1">#InlineCss-0 .button { color:     {{this.state.color
}

}
; 
}
</style>
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to change the styles for a DOM element with a 'button' class but you're not rendering that element in this react component. Wouldn't it make more sense to render that DOM element in this component?

Comment: Also, it'd be helpful if you could post your routes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html):

> In React, inline styles are not specified as a string. Instead they are specified with an object whose key is the camelCased version of the style name, and whose value is the style's value, usually a string.

It looks like you're most likely trying to set styles for a button that exists in components that are rendered in RouteHandler.

If that's the case, it would make the most sense for you to create a **wrapper** that wraps the other components and accepts the styles you're trying to set.

For example:

```
var PageWrapper = React.createClass({
  setHeaderStyle: function(data){
    var headerStyles = this.state.defaultStyles;
    if(data) {
      headerStyles.backgroundColor = data.first_colour;
      headerStyles.color = data.theme;
    }
    this.setState({
      branding: data,
      headerStyles: headerStyles
    });
  },
  render: function () {
    var buttonStyle = {
      color: this.state.color
    }
    return (
        <RouteHandler buttonStyle={buttonStyle} />
    );
  }
});

var Index = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
            <RouteHandler />
        </div>
    );
  }
});

var Signup = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p> Click below to signup now! </p>
        <button style={this.props.buttonStyle}>Click Me!</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Contact = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p> Click the button below to contact us </p>
        <button style={this.props.buttonStyle}>Email Us!</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var routes = (
  <Route path="/" handler={Index}>
    <Route path="page" handler={PageWrapper}>
      <Route path="signup" handler={Signup} />
      <Route path="contact" handler={Contact} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
);

ReactRouter.run(routes, function (Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});
```

**Edit:** Per your request, as an example to show how nested routes would work, I added a Signup and Contact component. If you look at the routes variable you can see how I nested these components under PageWrapper.

Now the nested routes `/#/page/signup` and `/#/page/contact` will both get access to the props that are added to the `<RouteHandler />` of PageWrapper. Hope this helps!!!!!

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, how would I layout my nested routes?

Comment: Hey, just added the example with nested routes. Sorry for the delay, was on vacation!